# MongoDB and C# driver socket timeouts in replica set with only one member

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a C# web app running which connects with c# driver 1.7.0.4714 to a MongoDB. I want to put this one MongoDB into a replica set with two secondaries. When I restart my original MongoDB in replica set mode it gets the primary but then most of the connections from my web app fail with

> *System.Net.Sockets.SocketException*

When I restart the MongoDB in non replica set mode everything works nicely again.

Here's my connection string: "mongodb://myserver:27017"

Comment: What is your code? What have you tried? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: the code might not be important. I use normal queries with C# driver 1.7.0.4714 with a simple connection string: mongodb://server:27017

Comment: What is the text of exception? Does your replica set works ok from mongo console? What actions cause exceptions: read, insert? Please, post your code where you initialize connection to mongo

Comment: RS is working fine from the console. It connects to the primary. Please see the conn string in the comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer which was quite easy, sorry to ask a dump question here:

I had my replcia set set up using domain names, i.e.

```
rs.add("myserver01")
rs.add("myserver02")
rs.add("myserver03")
```

The domain names `myserver01, ...,` could not be resolved on my application server and I  connected using IP addresses: `mongodb://10.0.0.1:27017,10.0.0.2:27017,10.0.0.3:27017`

So every 2nd or third request failed. Fixing the connection string to use domain names and also fixing that the domain names could be resolved fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to a replica set, normally the driver can figure out that it's connecting to a replica set or a stand-alone server.

You don't say which version of the C# driver you are using, and you don't provide exact format of connection string/syntax you are using, but the tutorial covers this in detail here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-MongoClientclass.

It indicates that if only one server is specified and you don't specify replica set name, then direct mode is used, which is not what you want.

You should be using either replica set mode explicitly rather than default automatic mode, or you should specify the replica set name.